# can a jersey http response fill object partially?

Tags: java, rest, http, jersey, jersey-client

I have this code:

RoutingResponse routingResponse = webResource.path("routingRequest")
                    .queryParam("at", rr.at)
                    .get(ClientResponse.class)
                    .getEntity(RoutingResponse.class);

the response `RoutingResponse` is quit big and I don't want to relate to all it's members.

How can I tell jersey to parse some inner calls members to plain string.

Something like that:

```
Class RoutingResponse
{

InnerClass innerClass1 : innerClass1: member1: 1, member1: 1;
String innerClass2 : "innerClass1: member1: 1, member1: 1";
}
```

Comment: You're going to want to do some research on Jackson features for that, as it's the one that's doing the deserialization

Comment: Following up on peeskillet. You can use @JsonIgnore for ignoring parts of your response. If you are using Xml you can configure the entity using Jaxb annotations to ignore certain parts of the response.

Comment: thanks. but i don't want to ignore. Just serialize some nested members  to string (JSON)